# Как переделать адаптер, что бы при нажатие открывал ссылку?

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть адаптер для `listview`,мне надо его переделать, что бы при нажатие открывалась ссылка, которая указанна в `link`. Запуская на телефоне, показывает
Вот код Адаптера

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "Тут URL";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String link = c.getString("link");
                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("link", link);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "link",},
                new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.link});
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(link[position-1]));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

**Update**
То есть у меня есть распарсенный массив, у него есть `id`,`name`,`link`,мне надо сделать, что бы при нажатию на например первый `name`, открывалась ссылка. которая написанно в `link`. Вставил полный код, может что припятствует.

**Update 2** Написал код, только теперь при `onItemClick`крашится

Comment: Может быть я ошибаюсь, но тут нет кода адаптера.

Answer (score 3):

Можно по разному сделать. Либо переопределить адаптер, создав свой, кастомный и в нём в `getView` повесить слушатель нажатий на разметку либо повесить слушатель нажатий на сам  `ListView` так:

```
lb.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
    {
        String url = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        //запускаем браузер по ссылке
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Не работает, может через getView попробовать?

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше написать кастомный адаптер и в ViewHoldere обработать клик

Comment: Как правильно его написать?)

Comment: вот здесь можно посмотреть пример http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html